# How can I troubleshoot a smelly shower drain in a tiled walk-in shower?

Tags: shower, p-trap

I had a plumber out. They told us use an enzyme down the drain. We used a whole bottle.  It helped a little for a while and then the smell got really bad again.

They did a smoke test and said that the rest of the hose was fine and no leaks. There was no smoke coming out of the shower drain but they left the rubber hot pad I had placed over it.  They said they could not run a camera down it because it would get stuck.

Now they are preparing a quote today to replace the trap. They said they could tunnel under the house to get to the trap and fix it. It sounds like it is going to be a very expensive undertaking. Should anything else be done before digging up everything?  Would a Sure Seal work or cause more problems?  This is a remodeled shower that was built 19 years ago.  This shower is used twice daily.

---

This is a remodeled shower that was built 19 years ago.  This shower is used twice daily. When the show is not in use it does not smell.  Then when you start taking a shower the smell gets awful!  I'm not really sure replacing the p trap will work since it does not stink before the shower.  I was also wondering is a Sure Seal would work?

Comment: Is this shower regularly used? Please revise to tell us more about the age and type of your plumbing and why you (they) think replacing the trap will solve the problem. Take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: See added comments

Comment: This is a remolded shower that was built 19 years ago. This shower is used twice daily. When the show is not in use it does not smell. Then when you start taking a shower the smell gets aweful! I'm not really sure replacing the p trap will work since it does not stink before the shower. I was also wondering is a Sure Seal would work? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't look like you took the tour. That information doesn't belong in an answer _or_ in comments. Please take the [tour], then _revise your post_ to include all relevant information.

Comment: Does your shower gurgle as it drains?

Comment: If the smell arises when you *start* to take a shower, but is not there just before, maybe it is your water supply that is smelly.    To test it, cover the drain very well then turn on the shower.    It's quite common, and normal that chlorine or sulphur in the water can be smelled in the shower much more than elsewhere in the house.

Answer (score 1):

> This is a remolded shower that was built 19 years ago.

They probably built it wrong.

A few things I can think of:

**Improperly sloped drain pipe**

If the drain pipe is improperly sloped then it could be causing draining issues; either backups or siphons.

**Undersized drain pipe**

If the drain pipe is undersized then the shower water is not able to hastily drain causing a backup of, unbeknownst to you, sewage water at your feet.

**S-Trap**

You might have an S-Trap in your shower which is siphoning the water out of the trap as it goes down and allowing sewer gases through.

**Improper venting**

If the drain isn't vented properly then this could cause drain flow issues.

---

Sadly, the only remedy for these situations is to gain physical access beneath the shower.

---

> They said they could not run a camera down it because it would get stuck.

Their specific camera would get stuck. Find a plumber that uses a smaller camera.

---

Last but not least there could be an unexpected blockage in the drain line somewhere causing a backup during your shower.

The plumber should be able to snake the entire drain line and clear anything that ***might*** be in the way.

Answer (score 0):

After 20 years you can get build up of scum at the top of the pipe from splashing. This should stink all the time though, but it can get worse when it gets wet. Most liquids you put down to clean like bleach will just drain past this and snakes won't get it unless they have bristles that are the correct size. We eventually just replaced them as part of a remodel.